# jquery mobile multiple html issue

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm developing a mobile app and I'm having doubts about page structure.

Currently I have multiple html files. It's not a problem, but I'd like to have always transitions between pages, that means all links need to be ajax enabled.

Well, the problem is I have some pages that have multiple data-role page inside, so in order to work I need to load those pages without ajax, so I have no transitions.
Those multipage html files are that way because I use the swipe to load different contents.

Is there a way to have transitions netween all pages and keepthis structure of some single html pages and some multipage html files?

Also, the app has around 20 different pages, I don't know if this is good to keep inside the same html file with diffrent data-role pages. I'm worried about performance of this solution, almost all pages read data from MySQL database.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't use multi-pages in multi-files. JQM catches/fetches only first page in each html file. Having all pages inside one html file wouldn't affect performance as pages are rendered once viewed.

Comment: so, which one do you think would be the best approach, a single html with all the pages or different html file for each one?